# Suggestion about writing a Java class which executes Test classes in the other modules of project

Tags: java, junit

I am using intellij idea 11 to develop a java project.

I have various modules under the project e.g. com.a.b.c which have src and test folders. The test folders are test route folders of the project. There are various test cases under that folders.

Now i need to write a new module which has a java class that invokes the test cases in various modules. I am not finding a way.

I have created a module e.g. com.a.b.testsuite and have added dependencies on those other modules where respective test cases are present.

Please suggest me a way further? Can i use JUnitCore class? i am not sure how to use that.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? use maven to build your project and it'll run the tests in each module as part of the build

Comment: Agreed; what's the ultimate goal?

Comment: i want to calculate the code coverage using intellij code coverage tool. So, i thought having a program to run all the test cases can help me have one program which runs test cases for all modules and gets the code coverage.

Comment: You can rate your code coverage using a cobertura plugin and maven.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone else has suggested - I would suggest converting your project to a Maven project.

Then create a profile in your POM and use the cobertura plugin something like this:

```
<profile>
        <id>testcheck</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <check>
                            <branchRate>0</branchRate>
                            <lineRate>0</lineRate>
                            <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                            <totalBranchRate>90</totalBranchRate>
                            <totalLineRate>90</totalLineRate>
                            <packageLineRate>0</packageLineRate>
                            <packageBranchRate>0</packageBranchRate>
                        </check>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

this really is the best way to go. Especially since each module you include in your project can also have it's own POM, with it's own coverage rates and checks.